# Override sc:Image alt text

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, alt

How can I override Sitecore `<sc:Image>` control so that it reads the alt text from another field in the same item?

I want to be able to give a tag,

```xml
<sc:Image contextAltText="fieldName" ...>
```

and it should first look at this field and if empty, it should render the `Media Item Alt` text as it normally does.

I don't need detailed implementation instructions. I only need to know which class and functions I have to overwrite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create you own class inheriting from the `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` and override it like this:

```cs
namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
    public class MyImage : Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Image
    {
        public virtual string ContentAltText { get; set; }

        protected override void PopulateParameters(Sitecore.Collections.SafeDictionary<string> parameters)
        {
            base.PopulateParameters(parameters);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Item[ContentAltText] ))
            {
                parameters.Add("alt", Item[ContentAltText]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe instead of calling `parameters.Add` you will need to replace the original `alt` value. I haven't tested the code so as you asked, it should only point you in the right direction.

---

**EDIT**: code below will not work with the `ContentAltText` being field name instead of different alt text.

There is also another way, but I don't know if this will override default `alt` value or this only works for new attributes:

```xml
<sc:Image runat="server" Field="Field Name" Parameters="alt=OverridenAltValue" />
```

---

**EDIT 2**:

To register your controls, find section below in `web.config` and add your namespace with your custom prefix:

```xml
<system.web>
  <pages>
    <controls>
      <add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Kernel"/>
      <add tagPrefix="msc" namespace="My.Assembly.Namespace" assembly="My.Assembly"/>
      ...
    </controls>
  </pages>
</system.web>
```

You may need to restart Visual Studio to make sure it recognizes new namespace.

Then use:

```xml
<msc:ImageWithAlt runat="server" ... />
```

Comment: ContentAltText is not the value of the alt text, but the name of the field in the same item where alt text value is to be found. So I need to reach another field of this item

Comment: See edited answer. Use `Item[ContentAltText]` to get value of the field.

Comment: Can you also please tell me shortly which configs should I modify to register this new user control? For example, as <sc:ImageWithAlt>